# How can I avoid the following error while trying to insert values into sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert one-to-many values in SQL. I have two tables: `users` and `userroles`.

I'm trying to insert several `userroles` for each user, where multiple roles already exist for these users. I'm using an insert statement but getting an error (shown below). I understand that the `userid` is likely my problem as it comes from the users table, but I don't know how to solve the issue... I thought the table would auto-insert an ID (the `UserRoles` table only contains 3 columns: `ID, UserID` and `RoleID`)

Syntax for adding two `RoleID` values for a given user:

```
insert into UserRoles (userid, roleid) 
values('9481EFEB-D36B-4381-8E9C-73EBC3BAC12D', '9ccc9a13-5027-48f9-9831-3e15afdb4412')
insert into UserRoles (userid, roleid) 
values('9481EFEB-D36B-4381-8E9C-73EBC3BAC12D', 'c12f6b95-7dc7-4fa1-8f91-f3fb7da4c0c3')
```

Error:

> Msg 4406, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Update or insert of view or function 'UserRoles' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

Comment: Are you inserting values into a table or a view? Because you cannot insert values into a view after it's creation, as the values come from an original table. Instead you need to insert the values into that table, and the view will be updated accordingly.

Comment: `UserRoles` is a `VIEW`, so what is the `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger you have on it, or the definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you've asked is a bit confusing. You mention you have two tables: users and userroles, but the update to userroles is clearly showing it's a view. I suspect there must be something else in your view definition, apart from just those three columns. Here's an example:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.UserRoles_table 
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    UserID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    RoleID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.UserRoles
AS
SELECT ID, UserID, RoleID 
FROM dbo.UserRoles_table;
GO

INSERT dbo.UserRoles (userid, roleid) 
VALUES('9481EFEB-D36B-4381-8E9C-73EBC3BAC12D', '9ccc9a13-5027-48f9-9831-3e15afdb4412')
INSERT dbo.UserRoles (userid, roleid) 
VALUES('9481EFEB-D36B-4381-8E9C-73EBC3BAC12D', 'c12f6b95-7dc7-4fa1-8f91-f3fb7da4c0c3')
GO
```

That works just fine. However if I add something else like this to the view definition, to perhaps have a special admin role or similar:

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.UserRoles
AS
SELECT ID, UserID, RoleID 
FROM dbo.UserRoles_table
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, '9481EFEB-D36B-4381-8E9C-73EBC3BAC13D', 'c12f6b95-7dc7-4fa1-8f91-f3fb7da4c0c4';
GO
```

Now notice when I try to insert again:

```
INSERT dbo.UserRoles (userid, roleid) 
VALUES('9481EFEB-D36B-4381-8E9C-73EBC3BAC12D', '9ccc9a13-5027-48f9-9831-3e15afdb4412')
INSERT dbo.UserRoles (userid, roleid) 
VALUES('9481EFEB-D36B-4381-8E9C-73EBC3BAC12D', 'c12f6b95-7dc7-4fa1-8f91-f3fb7da4c0c3')
GO
```

I get that same error: Msg 4406, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
Update or insert of view or function 'UserRoles' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

I hope that helps you find the issue.

Comment: Sorry Greg, you're right, my question was incomplete: the _userid_ field in the _UserRoles_ table originates in the _Users_ table (which contains numerous fields). But if that doesn't have anything to do with it I'm not sure what's going on. I'm still new to these tables, so I'll dig around as you've suggested, and report back. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Greg, I finally found the underlying table for this view and was able to make my needed changes. Thanks for your spot-on help!